# Why does ssh to a Chromebook now time out after rebooting it?

Tags: sshd, chrome-book

On a new Chromebook, I:

- Enabled the Linux environment.
- Configured and started sshd.
- Added appropriate `authorized_keys`.
- Was able to ssh in from a Ubuntu machine without a password.

Everything was fine.

After the Chromebook was powered off and rebooted:

- The Linux environment looked fine.
- `sudo systemctl status sshd` showed the daemon was fine.
- `ssh`ing to itself worked fine.

However:

- Attempts to ssh in from anywhere else now time out.
- Restarting the daemon doesn't help.

This is the result:

```
$ ssh -vvv  acer uptime
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ray/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/ray/.ssh/config line 15: Applying options for acer
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/local.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/local.conf
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "acer" port 2323
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to acer [10.0.3.13] port 2323.
… [2 minutes and 10 seconds later] …
debug1: connect to address 10.0.3.13 port 2323: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host acer port 2323: Connection timed out
```

I can't find any `journalctl` entries on the Chromebook since the original setup.

Looking at the Port Forwarding settings, I see that the toggle switch is off, *and disabled*:

[image: Port Forwarding settings with toggle switch disabled]

Any idea what's gone wrong?